# Split and check first 8 digits are met

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some data that looks like this, when reading this data from a file, is there a way to only add to the list if the first 8 digits are met?

```
11111111 ABC Data1
```

my current method is only splitting the space in between

```
Number = descr.split(' ')[0]
```

Comment: *is there a way to only add to the list if the first 8 digits are met* - what does that mean exactly? What if your example was "111111 ABC Data11" ?

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity to look up what a regex can do for you.

Comment: Are you saying the first 8 should be a digit? Something like `re.search('\d{8}', descr)` might work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only add a 8 digit number from an input string, do it as shown below

```
descr = input()
reqd_int = int( descr.split(' ')[0:8] )
```

This will fail if the input contains less than 8 integers at the start.

The other option is to use regular expressions, use it as shown below

```
import re
reqd_int = int(re.search('\d{8}', descr))
```

What the re.search() function does is,for the first paramete, `\d` stands for single integers and the `{8}` tells it to look 8 such contagious block of integers.

You can look up more on regular expressions [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=regex+cheat+sheet&ia=cheatsheet).